# Gaussian Like distribution with higher order moments

Tags: normal-distribution, sampling, exponential-family

For the Gaussian distribution with unknown mean and variance, the sufficient statistics in the standard [exponential family](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family) form is $T(x)=(x,x^2)$. I have a distribution that has $T(x)=(x,x^2,...,x^{2N})$, where N is kind of like a design parameter. Is there a corresponding known distribution for this kind of sufficient statistics vector? I need samples from this distribution so it is kind of crucial for me to get exact samples from the distribution. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried integrating to find the log-normalizer?

Comment: It is unclear whether you are talking about moments or sufficient statistics

Comment: @NeilG , I have a log-normalizer which is fairly complicated thing, what I really wonder is whether or not there is a known distribution with such sufficient statistics,

Comment: @Henry, I am talking about sufficient statistics, I kind of tried to make an analogy to the gaussian case, where sufficient statistics x corresponds to mean and x^2 corresponds to the variance/second order moment.

Comment: @YBE: Yes, it's a good question.  Out of curiosity, where did you encounter such measurements?  (In other words, what is motivating this choice of sufficient statistics?)

Comment: @NeilG,  This kind of sufficient statistics occured due to a Taylor expansion on some nonlinear function.

Comment: This is an unusual but interesting question. Usually we are given a parametric family of distributions that our data is suppose to come from and we ask what the sufficient statistics (minimal sufficient) are but here you turn the problem around and seem to be asking the following question "Given that I have a vector for the minimal sufficient statistics, what is the parametric family that it corresponds to?"  If you specify a minimal sufficient statistic without knowing the family how can you be sure that such a family exists?

Comment: @MichaelChernick: For a given sufficient statistic, carrier measure, and support, you can integrate the support to find the log-normalizer.  If the log-normalizer is finite, then I think the family exists.  He has done this and he is asking if this family has a name.

Comment: I can get samples from this distribution using importance sampling etc. but if there is an existing distribution that corresponds to my sufficient statistics, then I would like to know such a distribution and also whether I can sample exactly from that distribution.

Comment: @NeilG, do you know whether skewed-gaussian is from the exponential family? If so, what are the sufficient statistics? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @YBE: I don't think it is, because you have a term `\log(1+\erf(ax))`, which is not linear in `a`.  I could be wrong, though.

Comment: @MichaelChernick: as pointed out by Neil, given a reference measure, picking a vector of sufficient statistics and defining an exponential family are equivalent, provided the exponential function is integrable for some values of the parameter.

Comment: @YBE Is this intended for the construction of an exponential family with these sufficient statistics or can it be any parametric family of distribution where such variables form sufficient statistics.

Comment: @MichaelChernick, I have derived this in the standard exponential form format. But assuming the latter one you talked is also possible, how would it change the things?

Answer (score 4):

If you start with a "sufficient" statistic $T(x)$ then you can define an infinite number of distributions. Namely, for every measurable function $h(\cdot)$ against an arbitrary measure $\text{d}\lambda$ over your sampling space,
$$
f(x|\theta) = \exp\left\{ \theta\cdot T(x)-\tau(\theta) \right\} \,h(x)
$$
is a density from an exponential family and, for every $n$ and an iid sample $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ from this density, the statistic
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n T(x_i)
$$
is sufficient. For instance, for any measurable function $h$, you can define a density by
$$
h(x)\,\exp\{-(x-\mu)^2/\sigma^2\} \Big/ \int_{\mathbb{R}} h(y)\,\exp\{-(y-\mu)^2/\sigma^2\} \,\text{d}\lambda(y)
$$
which means that $T(x)=(x,x^2)$ is also sufficient for this distribution.

Hence, any pair $(h,T)$ defines an exponential family, which means your question has no answer.